# gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1

Tags: truffle, react, npm

I used the command `truffle unbox react` to build a dapp. It is just the initial step of my dapp development. However, it sucks. It continually pops up

```
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
```

this error. I've already google this error. Therefore, I set my python default version at 2.7 and install visual studio 2015 and visual studio 2017. Also I've
reinstall node-gyp and npm to make sure if it is  the latest version. I've tried whatever I can google. PLEASE HELP!
[image: This is my error]

Comment: Have you tried a one-time execution of `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools`?

Comment: @goodvibration I've already tried this command.

Comment: And did it complete successfully?

Comment: Yes, it completed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I was just going through this issue. I solved it by locally installing an earlier version of node. First, I deleted all my node modules and package-lock.json.

Then I installed an earlier version of node locally

```
npm install --save node@8.10.0
```

Then I re-installed all my other node packages

```
npm install --save drizzle drizzle-react drizzle components
```

Hope this might help.